# Frankenstein CSS - Stuck on how to manipulate the stylesheet

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Note: This Question Has a LOT of Information**

So I've been on this site all day attempting to figure out some code I inherited and the frankenstein mess I turned it into.  I've hit my third roadblock.  I've spent the entire day researching possibilities online..  Anyway, the situation.

I am building a website based on inherited code and pieces of other peoples stylesheets.  Currently the website is:  http://fracturedminds.net/newsite/portfolio.html  (currently with placeholder images, I do not claim rights to the images on this page)
The CSS is here:  http://fracturedminds.net/newsite/css/styles.css

I was attempting to mimic the horizontal scroll found on this site:  http://cameronrad.com/works and used snippets from his TWO css stylesheets:

1. http://cameronrad.com/cache/styles.css
2. http://cameronrad.com/skin/styles.css

now, the question...

How do I get the images to both scroll the way his does and to be in the center of the page so it scrolls THROUGH the nav section similar to his?

Or... If that is not an appropriate question, can anyone please tell me which sections of his stylesheet I should grab to learn from?  I don't even know which parts of the code correlate to the sidescroll!

I'm completely stuck!

Answer (score 0):

What I observed from the example website, he is using a jquery plugin for page side-scroll.
Maybe this demo and tutorial could be of some help to you -

Demo

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/

Tutorial

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/